# In case of two adjacent editable span and the cursor being in the middle, how html decide on which one i'm writing?

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

I have this script adding a new span inside an editable div each time the user input a dot in the input text, trying to separate text written in different spans based on the presence of a dot separating them.
(I use a custom tag 'mytag' but it behaves actually like a span)

```
<div style="border:1px solid black;" id='editor-container' contenteditable="true"><mytag id="0">test</mytag></div>
```

JS:

```
var divContainer = document.getElementById("editor-container");
var nodeIdIncrement = 0;
var htmlBefore = divContainer.innerHTML; 
var html;
var editedCharIndex;

moveCursorOnDiv("0");

divContainer.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
    html=divContainer.innerHTML;

    editedCharIndex=findFirstDiffPos(htmlBefore,html);
    console.log("html[editedCharIndex]: "+html[editedCharIndex]);

    if(html[editedCharIndex]=="."){
        nodeIdIncrement++; 
      htmlBefore=html.substring(0, editedCharIndex+1)+'</mytag><mytag id="'+nodeIdIncrement+'">'+html.substring(editedCharIndex+1);

      divContainer.innerHTML = htmlBefore;
      moveCursorOnDiv(nodeIdIncrement);
    }else{
        htmlBefore = divContainer.innerHTML;
    }

}, false);

// Find index of newly added character making a diff between previuos situation and present one
function findFirstDiffPos(a, b) {
   var shorterLength = Math.min(a.length, b.length);

   for (var i = 0; i < shorterLength; i++){
       if (a[i] !== b[i]) return i;
   }

   if (a.length !== b.length) return shorterLength;

   return -1;
}

function moveCursorOnDiv(divId){
    console.log("divId: "+divId);
  var el = document.getElementById(divId);
  console.log("inner: "+el.innerHTML);
  var range = document.createRange();
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  range.setStart(el, 0);
  range.collapse(true);
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range);
}
```

Here it is the [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/saga_shiftyblow/30oak21b/11/)

Let's say I input a char 'A' in the editable div "editor-container" the result will be:

```
<div style="border:1px solid black;" id="editor-container" contenteditable="true">
   <mytag id="0">A</mytag>
</div>
```

Then I add a dot. The result will be:

```
<div style="border:1px solid black;" id="editor-container" contenteditable="true">
   <mytag id="0">A.</mytag>
   <mytag id="1"></mytag>
</div>
```

When the dot gets added, I force programatically (function moveCursorOnDiv) the cursor to move on the new div. The expected result would be that input an another character 'B' would result in situation:

```
<div style="border:1px solid black;" id="editor-container" contenteditable="true">
   <mytag id="0">A.</mytag>
   <mytag id="1">B</mytag>
</div>
```

Instead it actually result in Chrome in:

```
<div style="border:1px solid black;" id="editor-container" contenteditable="true">
   <mytag id="0">A.B</mytag>
   <mytag id="1"></mytag>
</div>
```

While in Firefox behaves as expected 90% of times, but sometimes randomly behaves as in Chrome.

So, if I have the cursor between two adjacent span how html decide if the next input will be put in a span or in the other?
There's a way to force the expected behaviour?

**EDIT:** Pretty obviously, this happens only in case the following div is empty for there is ambiguity. If you put a char in the following div and move the caret in position '1' it works like a charm. (Just to say that the problem is not directly dependent from this specific code, which under different conditions works perfectly)

[JSFIDDLE 2](https://jsfiddle.net/saga_shiftyblow/ft1qd6xy/2/)

This means also the problem can be solved adding something like a &nb sp; when adding a new div, but it not a clean solution.

Comment: When I add a dot, the new `<mytag>` element is added with an `A` inside. Is that valid?

Comment: Yes with the second JSFiddle that is meant to show that particular case. Check the first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: You set `<div id="editor-container".....> </div>` as editable so when you are typing `.` it is creating a new `<mytag>` with a new `Id` but it is not giving an editable option to the new `<mytag>` and as it is not editable the mouse pointer remains in the same position.

Here I made some changes: Added some border and margin so that it is visible

```js
var divContainer = document.getElementById("editor-container");
var nodeIdIncrement = 0;
var htmlBefore = divContainer.innerHTML; 
var html;
var editedCharIndex;

moveCursorOnDiv("0");

divContainer.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
    html=divContainer.innerHTML;

    editedCharIndex=findFirstDiffPos(htmlBefore,html);
    console.log("html[editedCharIndex]: "+html[editedCharIndex]);

    if(html[editedCharIndex]=="."){
        nodeIdIncrement++; 
      htmlBefore=html.substring(0, editedCharIndex+1)+'</mytag><mytag id="'+nodeIdIncrement+'" contenteditable="true" style="margin: 10px;">'+html.substring(editedCharIndex+1);

      divContainer.innerHTML = htmlBefore;
      moveCursorOnDiv(nodeIdIncrement);
    }else{
        htmlBefore = divContainer.innerHTML;
    }

}, false);

// Find index of newly added character making a diff between previuos situation and present one
function findFirstDiffPos(a, b) {
   var shorterLength = Math.min(a.length, b.length);

   for (var i = 0; i < shorterLength; i++){
       if (a[i] !== b[i]) return i;
   }

   if (a.length !== b.length) return shorterLength;

   return -1;
}

function moveCursorOnDiv(divId){
    console.log("divId: "+divId);
  var el = document.getElementById(divId);
  console.log("inner: "+el.innerHTML);
  var range = document.createRange();
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  range.setStart(el, 0);
  range.collapse(true);
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range);
}
```

```css
mytag {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id='editor-container'>
    <mytag id="0" contenteditable="true">test</mytag>
</div>
```

In JS Made changes here:

```
htmlBefore=html.substring(0, editedCharIndex+1)+'</mytag><mytag id="'+nodeIdIncrement+'" contenteditable="true" style="margin: 10px; border: 1px solid black;">'+html.substring(editedCharIndex+1);
```

Comment: The idea is good, but this way the cursor is 'trapped' inside each editable div, i mean, if you're in a div you can't move to the following one only moving the cursor with arrows and it's a bit time consuming to control each time if you are at the end of a div, which is the following one and moving the cursor to it in order to have the user write on it. (The idea behind is using the parent div as an editor where people can write unaware of the hidden mytag, but writing in them with text separated by this 'dot' as separators)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set   as editable so when you are typing   it is creating a new  with a new Id but it is not giving an editable option to the new  and as it is not editable the mouse pointer remains in the same position.

changes I made: Added some border and margin so that it is visible

```js
var divContainer = document.getElementById("editor-container");
var nodeIdIncrement = 0;
var htmlBefore = divContainer.innerHTML;
var html;
var editedCharIndex;

moveCursorOnDiv("0");

divContainer.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  html = divContainer.innerHTML;

  editedCharIndex = findFirstDiffPos(htmlBefore, html);
  console.log("html[editedCharIndex]: " + html[editedCharIndex]);

  if (html[editedCharIndex] == ".") {
    nodeIdIncrement++;
    htmlBefore = html.substring(0, editedCharIndex + 1) + '</mytag><mytag id="' + nodeIdIncrement + '" contenteditable="true" style="margin: 10px;">' + html.substring(editedCharIndex + 1);

    divContainer.innerHTML = htmlBefore;
    moveCursorOnDiv(nodeIdIncrement);
  } else {
    htmlBefore = divContainer.innerHTML;
  }

}, false);



<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```css
mytag {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id='editor-container'>
    <mytag id="0" contenteditable="true">test</mytag>
</div>
```

```
function findFirstDiffPos(a, b) {
  var shorterLength = Math.min(a.length, b.length);

  for (var i = 0; i < shorterLength; i++) {
    if (a[i] !== b[i]) return i;
  }

  if (a.length !== b.length) return shorterLength;

  return -1;
}

function moveCursorOnDiv(divId) {
  console.log("divId: " + divId);
  var el = document.getElementById(divId);
  console.log("inner: " + el.innerHTML);
  var range = document.createRange();
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  range.setStart(el, 0);
  range.collapse(true);
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range);
}
```